# Getting negative numbers to show up in plugin charts

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a server which accepts file uploads and then processes them. This creates a queue of files to be processed and I'd like show both the total number of files in the queue and the rate of change(negative or positive).

Showing the total files in a plugin dashboard is easy, but when the rate of change is negative, my charts just go to zero and stay there. I know New Relic is recording the negative  values because I can see them in my summary metrics.

Is there any way to set the lower bound on a chart so queue progress can be monitored with New Relic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently any way to set or change the lower bound on a chart. With that said, there are still plenty of ways to show the data without modifying the lower bound.

A few ideas are:

- Calculate this as a percentage
- Show the positive change in one graph and the negative in another
- Use a table instead of a graph to show this information